# Why is it Orthodontics but Pedodontia?

Tags: suffixes, word-formation

Similarly we also have words like Periodontia and Exodontia and Endodontia (and Endodontics too apparently) and for many of them, I just can not find which one is correct?

Comment: The full OED definition for **periodontia** says *Dentistry (chiefly U.S.).  = **periodontics** n.* (it's also listed separately as the plural for *periodontium*, the periodontal ligament). But if I search for **periodontia** using Google, ***all*** the results on the first page are written in Spanish (including even Google's helpfully-supplied *definition*, despite the fact that my system is configured to *return search results in **English***). Which rather suggests that the definitions of "English" and "correct" are somewhat vague in the context of this question.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much! :)